# Database table structure

Tags: database, structure

I have seven combobox in a form. The selective items need prior maintenance in database through a form also. But, how to create a table which can store those items which are not bound to any primary key. All the fields will have different no of rows. Or I suppose to create 7 different tables for each item? Please help...

Shena

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown menus are often populated from tables which are basically just definitions of those different options.  Do each of the seven comboboxes control a completely different thing?  If you have seven independent fields, seven different tables to contain the standard options seems perfectly reasonable.

If you gave an example of what's in the different combo boxes, I might be able to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Yes, all have different control. I'm trying to maintain inventory details. The fields are cust_no (cust001, 002, 003, 004), inv_location (A, B, C, D, E), subcon_no (SUB01, 02, 03, 04 ,05 06),  p_status (G, R), item_cat (1, 2) and others are the same case. I'm just thinking that too many tables have to be created.

Comment: Starting out people are far more likely to create too **few** tables than too many.  Those all seem like good table candidates.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll maintain each in a separate table accordingly.